# Uniqueness of solution of nonlinear system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a complicated system of equations and I would like your help to provide conditions such that it has a unique solution.

In alternative, any direction on how to rewrite the system in a nicer way would be really useful and I will reward it.

The system is the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
d_k(Z_1,Z_2,..., Z_{11})=& \sum_{R_1=0}^1\sum_{R_2=0}^1 ... \sum_{R_{11}=0}^1 \sum_{X=1}^4 \Big[    c_k(R_1,R_2,..., R_{11}, X ) \\
\\
&\times \text{ } \Pi_{h=1}^{10} g_h(R_{12-h} , R_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h}, Z_{12-h+1},..., Z_{11}, X) \\
\\
& \times  b(R_1, Z_1, Z_2,..., Z_{11}, X)\\
\\
& \times a(X, Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_{11})\Big]\\
\\
& \text{ for each $Z_1\in \{0,1\}^2$, $Z_2\in \{0,1\}^2$, ..., $Z_{11}\in \{0,1\}^2$}\\
\\
& \text{ for each $k=1,..., 2^{11}-2$}
\end{aligned}
$$
[When I write $Z_1\in \{0,1\}^2$, I mean that $Z_1$ can take 4 values: $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)$]

The **terms that we know** are the functions on the left:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& d_k(Z_1,Z_2,..., Z_{11}) \\
& \text{ for each $Z_1\in \{0,1\}^2$, $Z_2\in \{0,1\}^2$, ..., $Z_{11}\in \{0,1\}^2$}\\
& \text{ for each $k=1,..., 2^{11}-2$}
\end{aligned}
$$

The **unknowns** are the functions on the right:

- **(A)**: $\hspace{1cm}c_k(R_1,R_2,..., R_{11}, X ) $
  $$
  \text{ for each $R_1\in \{0,1\}$,   ..., $R_{11}\in \{0,1\}$, $X\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, $k=1,..., 2^{11}-2$} 
  $$
- **(B)**: $\hspace{1cm} g_h(R_{12-h} , R_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h}, Z_{12-h+1},..., Z_{11}, X)$
  $$\text{ for each $R_{12-h}\in \{0,1\}$, $R_{12-h-1}\in \{0,1\}$,$Z_{12-h-1}\in \{0,1\}^2$, ..., $Z_{11}\in \{0,1\}^2$, $X\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, $h=1,..., 10$} 
  $$
- **(C)** $\hspace{1cm}  b(R_1, Z_1, Z_2,..., Z_{11}, X)$
  $$
   \text{ for each $R_{1}\in \{0,1\}$, $Z_{1}\in \{0,1\}^2$,..., $Z_{11}\in \{0,1\}^2$, $X\in \{1,2,3,4\}$}
  $$
- **(D)** $\hspace{1cm} a(X, Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_{11})$
  $$
  \text{ for each  $X\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, $Z_{1}\in \{0,1\}^2$,..., $Z_{11}\in \{0,1\}^2$}
  $$

There are some **constraints** which reduce the number of unknowns:

- $g_h(1 , R_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h}, Z_{12-h+1},..., Z_{11}, X)=1-g_h(0 , R_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h-1}, Z_{12-h}, Z_{12-h+1},..., Z_{11}, X)$
- $b(1, Z_1, Z_2,..., Z_{11}, X)=1-b(0, Z_1, Z_2,..., Z_{11}, X)$
- $ \sum_{X=1}^3 a(X, Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_{11})= 1-a(4, Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_{11})$

Therefore, from counting the cardinality of the codomains of the functions $\{d_k(\cdot)\}_{k=1}^{2^{11}-2}$, we have that
$$
\text{Number of equations:} \quad 4^{11}*(2^{11}-2)
$$

From counting the cardinality of the codomains of the unknown functions and  keeping in mind the constraints, we have that
$$
\text{Number of unknowns:} \quad \underbrace{(2^{11}*4)*(2^{11}-2)}_{(A)}+\underbrace{[2*4*\sum_{n=2}^{11}4^n]}_{(B)}+\underbrace{(1*4*4^{11})}_{(C)}+\underbrace{(3*4^{11})}_{(D)}
$$

We have less unknowns than equations (I made the computation in Matlab).

Comment: Maybe it would help to collapse all $R_k$ in a single binary number in $[0,2^{11})$ and all $Z_k$ in $[0,2^{22})$.

Comment: The issue with collapsing is that then I don't know how to write the functions $g_h$.